# Getting data from other sheets with dropdown menu

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets, google-docs

I want to get the datas from other sheets to the main sheet by selecting the store name from the dropdown menu on main sheet.

So on main sheet, i want people to select the store name from dropdown list and retrieve the product stock datas (all sheets have same product names) and allow them to change the stock values and store them to corresponding store sheets that i will hide.

Here is an example sheet i prepared:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BtrNKMSgurdft01P9Dw5MEh7rmYWPapwE18yhvDCdYE/edit?usp=sharing

Waiting for your help.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I think you will need something slightly more powerful than just formulas. Reading from other sheets is entirely possible, but storing to other sheets would require a macro. One way to store something in sheets without writing any code would be to use Google Forms.

Comment: If this is not Excel, remove the Excel tags. Google Sheets and Excel do not offer the same capabilities.

Comment: I am still waiting for help...

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve the first part with the `INDIRECT` function, which lets you convert a String into a Cell Reference or Named Range.

As an example, if you have Worksheets called `Sheet1` and `Other Sheet`, and a dropdown with those names in cell $A$1 of another sheet, then you can retrieve the value from cell $B$2 of those sheets like so:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & $A$1 & "'!$B$2")
```

Which will evaluate to one of the following:
`=INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!$B$2")`  >  `=Sheet1!$B$2`
or
`=INDIRECT("'Other Sheet!$B$2")`  >  `='Other Sheet'!$B$2`

This will *not*, however, let you send the data back to that sheet without delving into VBA.  If you don't want to do that, you might be better off changing your drop-down to a series of Hyperlinks along the top of your worksheets to go directly to the sheets?

Comment: will it just get what other sheets have?

Comment: Yes - it will let you Read from the other sheets, but not Write back to them